# Using C++ struct with iPhone app

Tags: iphone, c++, objective-c, constructor, struct

As I heard it is possible to use C++ Code within an iPhone (Objective C) project, I want to use an encryption library which is written in C++. However, the library uses a C++ type struct which uses a constructor, that I can't get right.

The Struct looks like this:

```
struct SBlock
{
 //Constructors
 SBlock(unsigned int l=0, unsigned int r=0) : m_uil(l), m_uir(r) {}
 //Copy Constructor
 SBlock(const SBlock& roBlock) : m_uil(roBlock.m_uil), m_uir(roBlock.m_uir) {}
 SBlock& operator^=(SBlock& b) { m_uil ^= b.m_uil; m_uir ^= b.m_uir; return *this; }
 unsigned int m_uil, m_uir;
};
```

full source is available here: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/security/blowfish.aspx

what's the easiest way to get around that issue?
I've read the article about using c++ code on apple's developer site, but that didn't help much.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's definitely possible and the trick is **extremely simple**: when you are going to use C++ code in your Objective-C++ applications, name your files **.mm** instead of **.m**.

So if you have `YourViewController.h` and `YourViewController.m`, rename the latter to be `YourViewController.mm`. It will cause XCODE to use C++ compiler instead of C compiler with your Objective-C++ code.

YourViewController.mm:

```
- (void) yourMessage {
    // will compile just fine and call the appropriate C++ constructor
    SBlock sb(1,1); 
}
```

Comment: well, I tried to rename the cpp class to mm. That still brought up the error in the .h file. However, I think you are trying to say that I should rename the file which includes the c++ code. When I think about that, this makes sense in end. Will give it a try and let you know. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Just change the filename extension of your .m file to .mm and include the C++ headers. Wow, I type too slow, lol.